# JSF error builting pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

guys I'm not sure that this problem is JSF or wildFly issue. I'm interested to know if anyone has encountered this problem
Only on Linux never in Windows
O.S RedHat CentOS 6.6
WildFly 10.1
Mojarra 2.2.13
Primefaces 6.0

Sometime application lose render capability (pages aren't builted properly on server) and this is an stack a part of stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.close(ResourceHelper.java:856)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:483)
...
at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87) 
at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
```

Watching GrepCode I found the piece of code that throw the exception

```
@Override
851 public void More ...close() throws IOException {
852
853 if (endOfStreamReached && !expressionEvaluated) {
854 info.disableEL();
855 }
856 inner.close();
857 super.close();
858
859 }
```

Where inner was teorically setted on

```
public More ...ELEvaluatingInputStream(FacesContext ctx,
682 ClientResourceInfo info,
683 InputStream inner) {
684
685 this.inner = inner;
686 this.info = info;
687 this.ctx = ctx;
688
689 }
```

Do you have any suggestion? Some timeout, some extra configuration or tips on linux system?
It's possible to catch the Exception and reinitialize in some way the application?
Thanks to everyone

**UPDATE**

Full stack Trace

```
2016-11-08 16:03:53,430 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46) java.lang.NullPointerException
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.close(ResourceHelper.java:856)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:483)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:403)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:115)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:380)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,431 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at it.onit.metrica.util.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:42)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,432 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,433 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-11-08 16:03:53,434 ERROR [stderr] (default task-46)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Is not related to xhtml*

After this error the application does not build any page correctly

Comment: Although the problem only occurs ON Linux, it is not a problem IN Linux. Hence the Linux tag is not correct, so I'm removing that. I doubt it is PrimeFaces related either, but please, please post a full stacktrace

Comment: there is probably an error in your xhtml, can you post that?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Sorry for being unresponsive, but I sometimes miss things. I'm not sure you got any further but similar (almost identical) issue was posted in the PrimeFaces forum and I did some investigation. Things can be read over there. https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=62080&sid=89e41ea2bda919d3fa44c55c4809a459#p182190